# Max voltage applied to MT1 of a triac

Tags: triac, shift-register

I plan to use a SN74HC595 shift register in a low voltage logic circuit to activate a 240v mains circuit using optocoupler and triac. The idea is that with each HIGH output latched to output, we get an accumulation of reactance in the lamp circuit. So, with all outputs high, the lamp will be brightest. For simplicity I omit the shift register circuitry. With a simple momentary switch I plan to send outputs HIGH, with another switch to reset.

[image: basic topology]

I am looking at the circuit so far and am wondering what will happen at MT1 of U2. Actually, I think the effect will be greatest at MT2 of the 8th triac ( not shown ), because with all 1-7 triacs conducting, the possible current which could flow into MT2 of the 8th triac will be greatest. But Maybe the lamp LED1 will source all the juice and I do not need to worry about this? I am just reminded that with transistors we can bias them by changing the emitter voltage, and wonder how a triac behaves under such conditions.

Perhaps my approach here is a cul-de-sac and I need to think again? Any more experienced eyes would be welcome here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The triacs are 'on' or 'off'. If the triac is 'on' most of the voltage that doesn't appear across the lamp will appear across the series capacitor. If the triac is 'off' most of the voltage that does not appear across the lamp will appear across the triac.

You should have series resistors on the optocoupler LED inputs.

Comment: OK. It sounds like there is no way then, that the triac can be triggered by a voltage at MT1.
Yes, I'll be putting maybe a 330 ohm in there; I believe the MOC3063 triggers at around 5ma.